# Understanding supremum

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, then $M = \sup A$ if and only if:
(a) $M$ is an upper bound of $A$;
(b) for every $M′ < M$ there exists $x\in A$ such that $x > M′.$

My question is: I didn't understand $(b)$, can you explain clearly?

Comment: Can you write down the definition of supremum of a set?

Comment: You can also call the $\sup$ the *least upper bound of the set*. In other words, if $M=\sup A$, then no real number less than $M$ is an upper bound of $A$. What does this mean?

Comment: @mfl Definition. Suppose that $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a set of real numbers. If $M \in \mathbb{R}$ is an
upper bound of $A$ such that $M ≤ M′$
for every upper bound $M′$ of $A$, then $M$ is
called the supremum of $A$, denoted $M = sup A$.

Comment: @Siddhant I don't know $(b)$ what this does mean.

Comment: So, since for every $M'<M$ there exist $x\in A$ such that $x>M'$ you have that $M'$ is not an upper bound of $A.$ Can there exist an upper bound $N$ of $A$ such that $N<M?$

Comment: @mfl What is the $X$ mean?

Comment: @mfl it should be $x$?

Comment: Yes. Typo fixed.

Comment: @mfl there can't.

Comment: @mfl thanks....

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use $m=supA$, since I don't want a set and its element to be denoted by the same uppercase letters. Coming to your question,

(b) means that if an element $m'$ of $A$ is such that $m'<m$, then $m'$ cannot be an upper bound.

In other words, it means $m'$ is the least of all the upper bounds of $A$ and hence its other name "least upper bound".

Answer (score 0):

Well, in plain english, one could say that the supremum of a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the **lowest upper bound** of the set. This means that, for a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let's say A, a number $M$ is it's supremum if and only if:

1. $M$ is an **upper bound** for A, which means that for every $x\in A$, $M$ satisfies the inequality:
   $$x\leq M$$
2. $M$ is the **lowest** upper bound, which means that every other real number $M'$ that is larger than $M$ is an upper bound of $A$ or, equivalently, that every other number $M'$ that is lower than $M$, is **not** an upper bound of $A$.

Now, a number $M'$ not being a bound of a set $A$, is equivalent to being able to "find" a number $x$ belonging to $A$ that is larger than $M'$. By this last sentence, it is where your second condition comes from.